# Video software that can move, rotate, and zoom pictures

Tags: video, video-editing, animation

I'm looking for a software (for OS X, preferably) that can

- move a picture along an adjustable curve
- rotate (animated rotation) a picture the full 360 (can rotate a custom amount, not just fixed amounts like 90 degrees), clockwise and counter clockwise.
- zoom in and out of the pictures
- control the speed at which all this is happening.

(I'm making a kind of 2D animation video, with layers of the scene overlapping to fake depth and stuff, if that helps)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) you can attach a picture or even a video to a surface as a texture and manipulate animate the motion of that surface in full 3-D - *for 2-D just limit the motion to one axis*. There is even an entry in the manual on how to do it [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/video.html).

Once you have defined your surface and its texture and motion you can render it into a movie.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Generate various format movies
- Lots more that you can do!